# Is it possible to configure 2 productlevels?

Tags: products-management, products

I am running into a problem trying to configure my catalog.
I set up a category tree. 
I can now add products to the deepest level. 
But what I want is a deeper product level under this product level.

The productlevel under the deepest category should contain images, files, descriptions, drawings, etc… in tabs.
But no price info, as the actual varieties vary in price!
I want the level under this to contain the actual varieties in the product with prices. And this can be a list only. 
A little difficult to explain.

Please have a look at **https://www.etk.nl/nl/catalog/inbouw/downlighters-led/cis-v16** where *CIS-V16* is my actual product and the *cis16-2700w* etc. are the unique article codes of the variaties with their prices.

I cannot use a drop down menu and use configurable products, as there are no recurring options, they are too divers.

I am getting a little desperate, I have tried all and browsed the internet, but no clue how to solve this. 
But I have to say that I just started using Magento, so I might overlook something.
(Link to my test website: http://www.etk-mood.nl/shop/catalogus/inbouw/downlighters-led.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I just need to use grouped products. I thought that option had another functionality. I will try that out. My apologies for not having looked into this properly before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this as an answer so that the question doesn't stay unanswered: You are probably looking for grouped products.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had added a comment to my initial question, but that probably does not count as an answer. Thanks for looking though.